# How To Plug In A PCI Express 2.0 x16 Card Into A x1 Extension Cable?

Tags: graphics-card, gpu, cable, pci-express

I bought some PCIe x1 extension cables off of ebay for a few bucks each.

They came only ready to accept x1 sized cards.

I drilled out one side of the extension cables to allow for a x4, x8 or x16 sized card be fit inside of them.

When I connect the x16 GPUs to my motherboard via the PCIe x1 cables, they are not recognized.

I am told I might have to "bridge" the PCIe extension cable, like so:

[image]

Is this all I need to do? Don't want to short my GPUs or my motherboard or anything! I only have one :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that you needed to bridge pins A1 and B17 on the pcie 1x extension cable to recognize the other cards.